# Assigning two routes to the same category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I wonder if it is possible to assign two routes to the same category. For example:

- By accessing http://myblog.com/action or http://myblog.com/movie-action, leads me to the same category destination.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i Think this plugin can handle this
http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

it makes all kind of redirections in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make all posts have both categories and then the links come up the same.

However, to do literally what you are asking, let's say you want to get to Category Action through Category Movie Action. [See making categories in the Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates#What_Template_File_is_Used.3F)

Create a .php file for the category you want to redirect. In this, make

```
category-movie-action.php
```

In this file, you can just paste [the code](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ht/phpredirection.htm)

```
<?php
   header( 'Location: http://myblog.com/action' ) ;
?>
```

And that should redirect anyone who goes to that particular category. If you need a more elegant solution I'm sure there are ways as well.